# Re indexing issue in Magento 2.1.9

Tags: magento2.1

Can anyone help me to short out reindexing issue.

My version is 2.1.9
Total number of products is over 1 million.

Re indexing always showing running.

Comment: Try to provide more details or it is difficult to understand what is going on... are you reindexing all the indexes together? what is the output of 'magento indexer:status'?

Comment: Thank you for comment @sissy its working fine but taking too much time to complete it. So, is there any solution of mechanism to make it fast ???

Comment: I setup the cron as per requirement and its working fine now.